# Magento - VAT for shipping

Tags: magento

I'm trying to figure out where to locate the function(s) that set the VAT for the shipping in Magento; both in the checkout and in the order made by the customer. If possible, the last function that is run that calculates the final VAT for the shipping might be the best one to override. The thing is that I want to make the VAT for shipping vary depending on the VAT on the products in the cart.

Take for example two products that cost 100$ each.

One product has a 25% VAT, while the other product has a 12.5% VAT.

Now, what I'd like to do is to calculate the VAT of the shipping by running the following calculation:

```
((100*25)+(12.5*100))/200 = 18.75
```

This would mean that the VAT on the shipping would be 18.75%.

While I'm on it, I also wonder how to get the VAT for each product in the cart, since each product can have a different tax-class.

Comment: What Magento version are you on? I believe this feature is built-in from 1.7

Comment: I'm using Magento Enterprise Edition. The latest version, of course.